# Stored Procedure Create Prob

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Ok I don't know much about stored procedures, but does anyone know how I could write this as an SP. I think it's kinda getting there but not quite. basically what would I need to paste into my query to create it!:)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_executesql
as
DECLARE
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@y    AS INT,
@sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Construct the column list for the IN clause
SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(w) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT WeekNo AS W FROM dbo.Items) AS W
ORDER BY W
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');


-- Construct the full T-SQL statement
-- and execute dynamically
SET @sql = N'SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT ItemNo, WeekNo, Value
                    FROM dbo.Items) AS I
            PIVOT(SUM(Value) FOR WeekNo IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the query statement is correct and you need just a SP structure it will be like this:

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NAME
@variable1 type [input/output]
as
begin
--query
end

//to execute SP
EXEC SP_NAME 'valueForVariable1'

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Just don't name provedure sp_executesql, name it get_items or something else.

new procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_items

as
declare @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@y AS INT,
@sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(w) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT week_no AS W FROM weekly_items) AS W
ORDER BY W
FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, N'');

SET @sql = N'SELECT *
FROM (SELECT item_no, week_no, totval
FROM weekly_items) AS I
PIVOT(SUM(totval) FOR week_no IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

GO
```